# How do I store multiple values along with a single key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to insert multiple values with a single key in javascript array object using loops. I am creating an event calendar to add events to the calendar. My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var a=<?php echo(json_encode($da)); ?>;
        var ev=  <?php echo(json_encode($eve)); ?>;
        var codropsEvents ={};
        for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {

            codropsEvents[a[i]] = '<span>'+[ev[i]]+'</span>';

        }

        </script>
```

Using this code I got something like this,

```
var codropsEvents={[date1]:[event1],[date1]:[event2]}
```

but my calendar plugin does not support multiple events on the same day like this. It only supports like the following

```
var codropsEvents={[date1]:['event1','event2'],[date2]:['event3','event4']};
```

Please anyone can help me
NB: $da is the date array and $ev is the events in each date

Comment: what does not work with the above code? do you have some more examples?

Comment: please add the value of `a` and the wanted result.

Comment: could you please explain it.. Where to add value of a

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.push` method on an array. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

For example:

If you have an object like yours:

```
var codropsEvents = {[date1]: [], [date2]: []}
```

And you want to put events into those dates,

```
codropsEvents[date1].push("event1")
```

This will push `event1` to `date1`, so do something like this in your loop:

```
 for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
     codropsEvents[a[i]].push(ev[i]);
 }
```

Comment: here the variable 'a' specifies the date of event. So that how can I cannot define like date1, date2 etc. date is dynamically added events by the user

Comment: when I use this code like
`var codropsEvents={[a]:[]}
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
     codropsEvents[a[i]].push(ev[i]);
 }`
it returns nothing. is there any problem with this code